# how can I make the Group Box only external line without background

Tags: c#, winforms

I have drawings on the form, and the Group Box hides them. And it also prevents the activation of a click event of the form. So I tried to set the background color with alpha element completely transparent, then I can see the paintings, but events still do not work. Is there a possibility Group Box will be no fill at all, only an outside line?

Comment: Do you mean to remove the outside line?

Comment: if you dont want to fill the groupbox or groupbox contains nothing then why are you using the groupbox?

Comment: I mean to erase the background, leaving the outside line

Comment: I use a Group Box to show together a specific set of drawings

Comment: then why dont u draw on the groupbox instead of drawing on the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are trying to draw on the form and want to have inside the boundaries of a `groupbox`, you should try to draw on groupbox instead of form.

```
Graphics groupBox = groupBox1.CreateGraphics(); //Graphics for GroupBox
```